# How should I add an outlet in the middle of a split parallel circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an outlet which is split, with the bottom outlets on a switch. Both top and bottom are on one 15amp breaker.

I am adding one new outlet in the middle of the run and need to split off the wires on the back of the outlet and come back to the wires on the back of it.

Do I just use tap wire connectors on all the wires?

[image: back of plug]

[image]

Comment: is this outlet half-switched, or is this outlet fed by a double-breaker or two handle-tied singles (or two different breakers, period - what was acceptable varied over time, and unacceptable work is not unusual)

Comment: Is one of these sockets controlled by a switch?  Can you measure 240V between black and red?  Does it require turning off 2 circuit breakers (or a doubled breaker that is handle-tied) to turn off this outlet?  (warning: it might! Check ALL wires for hot!)

Comment: @user158724 modifying or commenting on the closed question is not helpful, place comments here or modify this question to provide the requested clarifications, or it may be closed since it's not answerable without context from both questions. VTC

Comment: Question updated with information from [a duplicate](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/260246/35141). Voting to reopen.

Answer (score -1):

That outlet is on what is called a MWBC circuit.  The top and bottom receptacles are on two different breakers(hopefully with a handle tie).  A MWBC uses two hots but share the neutral, makes adding a GFCI a bit more difficult.

The tab between the two hot screws is removed/missing.

That outlet is also passing power to another outlet. Two blacks and the two reds, one brings power in, and the other power out.

To add another outlet, just wire it the same, making sure to remove the tab between the two hot screws.  Connect a new cable using pigtails. Wire the two reds plus the new red and a short red with a wire nut. The short red will go to the screw the red was on.  Repeat with the blacks.  Repeat with the white neutrals.

Make sure power is off by checking with a meter on both the red and black before removing/touching.

[image]

Comment: MWBC or switched hasn't been established yet. And it's not wired correctly if it is  an MWBC (neutrals should be pigtailed) which means if it was competently installed (which we don't know one way or the other) it isn't.

Comment: why would there be wires in the back of the plug and also on the hot screws?

Comment: A multi-wire branch circuit in a residential dwelling contains two 120V wires of **different phases** (A and B phase) and share one neutral wire as return current.

Comment: @user158724 the plug is used as junction box

Comment: With an ordinary circuit typical is in to one screw out on the other screw. With MWBC the screws are not linked. Solution is either to also use backstabs (which previous installer did) or pigtails (highly recommended).

Comment: i aqppreciat all the professional input. I cant find a photo or diagram that shows how to do this, your descriptions are great I just want to make sure I am able to do it correctly.

Comment: @user158724   Taking your outlet without changing/adding anything, you would take the two reds off of the outlet and with a wirenut add a short piece of red wire.  The short red wire would then be place around the screw, without using the back stab(hole).  To add another outlet, just add the new red wire to the wire nut(making sure it is the right size for four wires).  Repeat for the blacks and whites.

Comment: @user158724 On cheapo outlets, every backstab is near a screw. The screw and backstab are internally connected. So they are using the stab+screw as a quick way to splice those two wires *two each other* and also to the socket.   The better $4 outlets provide a much better way to do that.  Backstabs are notoriously unreliable.

Comment: This answer leaves quit a bit unsaid regarding connections and connectors. It also falsely states the existence of a MWBC.